# Bootstrap 5.1 toggle not closing after opening(latest version)

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm in the process of learning JS and have made a collapsable navbar. I got the menu to
open upon clicking the button, but it will not close. I've searched this site for
answers but anything I've found refers to Bootstrap. This is just pure JS. I've also
looked over my code for hours trying to spot a syntax error or anything that could be
going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I am working on the latest version of bootstrap which 5.1 and facing this problem.

I am not able to resolve this. Navbar toggler is not closing after opening.
Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark  ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Help me regarding this issue.
I have included js bootstrap already.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** -

1. comment out Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS
2. Navbar code structure modified as per bootstrap site

**Ref URLs** -

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#external-content
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

---

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="bg-dark p-4">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with @Pinaki that you should use the JS Bundle instead of using Bootstrap JS and Popper JS separately. So you can remove option 2 from your code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

<!doctype html>

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">tindog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="bg-dark p-4">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you must remove bootstrap bundle library,then run again